# How can I make libstemmer work with sphinx in Debian?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I try to activate libstemmer for a website.
My sphinx version is Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117) on a Debian server, and everything is working fine in my dev env (Mac OSX, same sphinx).

I have this error while indexing :

```
invalid morphology option 'libstemmer_french' - IGNORED
```

My options are

```
min_prefix_len = 4
enable_star = 1
html_strip = 1
charset_table = (...)
morphology = libstemmer_french
```

After reading more about libstemmer, I suspect that my sphinx install does not support libstemmer.
It is a production server so I can't afford to try and fail too much. My questions are :

- How can I check if libstemmer has been compiled with sphinx ?
- How can I install libstemmer above sphinx / or reinstall sphinx in a safe way ?

Note : I installed sphinx using :

```
apt-get install sphinx
```

...so no idea of the configure options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx by default works only with Russian and English stemming. You have to compile sphinx with another version libstemmer_c to get support for french stemming:

Please, follow these steps:

1) Get the last sphinx version:

```
svn checkout http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sphinxsearch-read-only
```

2) Get the libstemmer_c library:

```
wget http://snowball.tartarus.org/dist/libstemmer_c.tgz
```

3) Replace libstemmer_c in sphinx source directory:

```
tar xf libstemmer_c.tgz && cp -rfp libstemmer_c/* sphinxsearch-read-only/libstemmer_c/
```

4) Configure sphinx with appropriate parameters:

```
./configure --enable-id64 --with-libstemmer && make
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method, now libstemmer_french seems to be ok when indexing. The problem is that you made me install sphinx 2.1.0, which is not compatible with thinking sphinx anymore.

Comment: It worked, I just had to update thinking-sphinx to 1.4.11 and riddle to 1.5.1, and rebuild the index. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

At least here on my Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS install i could already use [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) stemmers included in the libstemmer0d package, which i simply had to `apt-get install`, too. No need to compile anything.